# Unable to Install TWRP / Cyanogenmod on Moto G 2013

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, motorola-moto-g

I have a Moto G 2013 (XT1033). The device does not boot successfully - only shows the logo and then just shows a blank screen. So I tried to install Cyanogenmod hoping it might work out. I have unlocked the bootloader.

I tried installing TWRP recovery image (3.0.2.0) from TWRP official site using the command

```
$ fastboot erase recovery
erasing 'recovery'...
(bootloader) Erase allowed in unlocked state
OKAY [  0.046s]
finished. total time: 0.046s
$
$ fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.0.2-0-falcon.img 
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'recovery' (9488 KB)...
OKAY [  0.331s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.175s]
finished. total time: 0.507s
```

And the device shows the following text:

```
cmd: getvar:partition-type:recovery
cmd: erase:recovery
cmd: getvar:partition-type:recovery
cmd: getvar:max-download-size
cmd: download:00944000
cmd: flash:recovery
Mismatched partition size (recovery)
```

[image: Bootloader Screen during Recovery Image Installation]

When I boot into the recovery, it displays a Unlocked bootloader warning, then a blank screen for 2-3 seconds and then an image of resting android bot with a red exclamation over its belly, with "No command" caption.

[image: No Command Screen]

**No TWRP Recovery Screen**.

Then I pressed Vol UP + Power button for 2-3 seconds and that displayed the Android system recovery screen. Now I selected "apply update from ADB". Then I tried the following command:

```
adb sideload cm-12.1-20151117-SNAPSHOT-YOG7DAO1K9-falcon.zip
```

I get the following error in the Android System Recovery screen:

```
E:failed to verify whole-file signature
E:signature verification failed
Installation aborted
```

[image: Sideload failure due to Signature Verification failed]

The Cyanogenmod zip file is not corrupted since the SHA1 hash is the same as the one provided in Cyanogenmod downloads page. Please help me to install Cyanogenmod on Moto G (XT1033).

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You cannot side load zip files through stock recovery which are not signed by your vendor, so don't bother with side load. We can discuss details later. Now, can you rename that TWRPimage to recovery.img and from bootloader mode issue the command `fastboot boot recovery.img`?

Answer (score 6):

As it's obviously the *stock recovery* you've used to flash CM, that won't work as it will do a signature check and thus reject the ZIP as being invalid. So here's what you do instead:

1. put `cm-12.1-20151117-SNAPSHOT-YOG7DAO1K9-falcon.zip` onto your device's SD card
2. boot into bootloader
3. now *boot* (not install) TWRP: `fastboot boot twrp-3.0.2-0-falcon.img`
4. TWRP will show up on your device. Chose "apply update from SD card", navigate to where you put your CM `.zip`, select it, confirm

Worked for me, though on a different device.

Comment: Just saying wouldn't it be better to install and boot? Because if anything goes wrong you can always go back to recovery without being tethered to a pc

Comment: @lolreppeatlol you've noticed that OP tried that and failed?

Comment: ummm whoops! lol

Comment: Giving error 
`downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  0.344s]
booting...
FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 0.359s`

Comment: @LaxmikantDange Bootloader locked? Then it will fail.

Comment: I unlocked the bootloader then it worke, Thanks. :)

Comment: FWIW, to unlock your bootloader, [this page describes an official way](https://www.howtogeek.com/239798/how-to-unlock-your-android-phones-bootloader-the-official-way/). PS: Some phones are just can not be unlocked, such as my Moto X 1st gen. :-/

Comment: This works quite good! Flashing the bootloader had not worked, but booting it does! Installed LineageOS this way. Thanks